# Coded UI: HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create test that runs my application and enter text in the field using CodedUI.This is my code:

```
 var app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\app.exe");
 var loginEdit = new WinEdit();
 loginEdit.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.ControlName, "textEditLogin");
 loginEdit.Text = "test005";
```

Error: `System.NotSupportedException: SetProperty "Text" is not supported on control type: Window.`

If i use this code:

```
Keyboard.SendKeys(loginEdit, "test005");
```

I have error: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException: (Failed to get the message for an exception of type Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException due to an exception.) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component`

This is properties of my WinEdit:
[WinEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7tZO.png)

What could be the problem?

Comment: That is a WinWindow, not a WinEdit.  Use a [basic tutorial](http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/windows-automation-testing-coded-ui/) to get this right.

Comment: I don't really understand why that Control is WinWindow? 
Because ControlType of this control is "Edit". And if it is WinWindow how can i enter text in this control?

Comment: When I changed control type of loginEdit (WinWindow) and trying "Keyboard.SendKeys(loginEdit, "test005");" I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in object browser, where I didn't see control that I need.
I used recorder for locating my WinEdit and wrote this code:

```
var loginWindow = new WinWindow();


loginWindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "layoutControl1";
loginWindow.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));

var loginEdit = new WinEdit(loginWindow);
loginEdit.WindowTitles.Add("layoutControl1");

Keyboard.SendKeys(loginEdit, "test005");
```

Comment: In the future one technique you may want to adopt is using [Draw Highlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.drawhighlight.aspx) to make sure you're attempting to interact with the correct control.